# why this dos command does not work inside python?

Tags: python, subprocess

I try to move some dos command from my batch file into python but get this error, The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect, for the following statement.

```
subprocess.Popen('rd /s /q .\ProcessControlSimulator\bin', shell=True, 
                  stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

if I just copy that dos command into window console, it works. The os.getcwd() gave me expected working directory.

My questions are:
1. why is that?
2. how to avoid that? do I need to get current working directory and construct an abstract path for that command? how to do that?

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "Not working"? Are you reading its output from the PIPE?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`\` (backslash) is an escape character within string constants, so your string ends up changed. Use double `\`s (like so `\\`) within string constants:

```
subprocess.Popen('rd /s /q .\\ProcessControlSimulator\\bin', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Comment: I also suggest to check out the recommendation in other answers to check out the `os` module for functions doing file and directory manipulations.

Answer (score 9):

My advice is try not to use system commands unnecessarily. You are using Python, so use the available modules that come with it. From what i see, you are trying to remove directories right? Then you can use modules like shutil. Example:

```
import shutil
import os
path = os.path.join("c:\\","ProcessControlSimulator","bin") #example only
try:
    shutil.rmtree(path)
except Exception,e:
    print e
else:
    print "removed"
```

there are others also, like os.removedirs, os.remove you can take a look at from the docs.

Comment: Also, don't catch the exception. Let it fly - unless you're going to do something about it.

Answer (score 7):

You've got unescaped backslashes.  You can use a python raw string to avoid having to escape your slashes, or double them up:

```
subprocess.Popen(r'rd /s /q .\ProcessControlSimulator\bin', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

or

```
subprocess.Popen('rd /s /q .\\ProcessControlSimulator\\bin', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't just copy it one-to-one. For example, your escape characters () become incorrect. You may need a double \ in this case.

Also, there are specific API calls for creating and killing directories, look at os.path