# unable to use cmd command in python

Tags: python, shell

I am using this command to find disk usage in my shell script

```
df -h | awk '$NF=="/"{printf "Disk Usage: %d/%dGB (%s)\n", $3,$2,$5}'
```

I want to use this command in my python script

```
ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command("df -h | awk '$NF=="/"{printf "Disk Usage: %d/%dGB (%s)\n", $3,$2,$5}'")
```

but unable to handle string literals.

I tried replacing \ with \\ as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102452/why-this-dos-command-does-not-work-inside-python)

Can someone throw light on thiS?

This is the error i am getting

```
ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command("df -h | awk '$NF=="/"{printf "Disk Usage: %d/%dGB (%s)\n", $3,$2,$5}'")
                                                                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not escaping your double quotes and they are terminating the string early:

```
ssh.exec_command("df -h | awk '$NF==\"/\"{printf \"Disk Usage: %d/%dGB (%s)\\n\", $3,$2,$5}'")
```

Comment: the execution of this command gives no output, and when i print ssh_stderr.read() this is the error i am getting awk: cmd. line:1: $NF=="/"{printf "Disk Usage: %d/%dGB (%s)
awk: cmd. line:1:                 ^ unterminated string
awk: cmd. line:1: $NF=="/"{printf "Disk Usage: %d/%dGB (%s)
awk: cmd. line:1:                 ^ syntax error

Comment: Can you please review your answer??

Comment: Sorry, I missed escaping the newline character. I've just tested this for myself (using `subprocess.Popen()`) and it's working for me.

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following using [shlex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html) and [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) to prepare your command string.

```
from subprocess import list2cmdline
import shlex

cmd = list2cmdline(shlex.split("""df -h | awk '$NF=="/"{printf "Disk Usage: %d/%dGB (%s)\n", $3,$2,$5}'"""))

ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd)
```

Comment: this also is not working 
same error like in kfb's answer